# How to extract the last word from the last line of a TXT file through a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to extract the last word from the last line of a txt file.
[image: corner.txt]

The result I want is just **Cup$2!**.

This is what I tried:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set L=1
for /F "tokens=2 delims=" %%a in (corner.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  if !L!==7 set Line7=%%a
  set  /a  L=!L!+1
)

echo The word is %Line7%
pause
```

The result I'm getting is **The word is**.

What should I edit to get the above result?

Comment: What other punctuation counts as separators? I'd expect the last word to be `Cup&2!/Cup$2!` since the `$` and `!` are also not separators.

Comment: @SomethingDark...usage of & and ! is not constant it could be anything eg. Cup567/Cup241 or anything else ...but the result should always be the last one...i.e Cup241(in this case)

Comment: so just tabs, spaces, and `/`s?

Comment: You've stated that you want the second token, but you have no delimiters, therefore there is only one token!

Comment: @SomethingDark...pretty much ..yes

Comment: @Compo, so what would you suggest, i edit in the script so that i cud get the expected result?

Comment: Please post text as such rather than as image! Anyway, type `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and reread the `for /F` section; you will find out that you need to set the `delims=` option to split a line into multiple tokens…

Comment: @aschipfl...got your point of splitting the line into tokens but i'm confued what should i mention in delims= for the last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you could capture the substring you require, from reading your code, i.e. the last substring on the seventh line:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
    Set "var="
    For /F UseBackQ^ Skip^=7^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("corner.txt") Do Set "var=%%~nxG" & GoTo Next
    If Not Defined var GoTo EndIt

    :Next
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo The word is !var!
    EndLocal

    :EndIt
    Echo Press any key to close . . .
    Pause 1>NUL
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

If however, as your question title and body asks, you want the last substring of the last line, it's a little bit simpler:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
    Set "var="
    For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("corner.txt") Do Set "var=%%~nxG"
    If Not Defined var GoTo EndIt
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo The word is !var!
    EndLocal

    :EndIt
    Echo Press any key to close . . .
    Pause 1>NUL
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

I will not however be explaining any of it, please use the search facility at the top of the page, and the output from the built in help for each of the commands I have used.

Comment: I would assume the OP wants something generic without hardcoding a line skip.

Comment: Okay, I used their code, as my basis, but given the title and the body text, @Anders, I've provided additional and simpler code for the last line too.

Comment: What is this `Delims^=^` caret syntax? (A bit hard to Google)

Comment: It's still 'no delimiters' @Anders. You'll note that those parameters are not enclosed within double-quotes, so the spaces and `=` characters require escaping. I've used that syntax simply to ensure that I could have no end of line. A default EOL is the semi-colon, `;`, which means that any lines which begin with one would be omitted. As it is impossible for me to know if any line could ever begin with a semi-colon, and it is possible that the code may be used for specific line numbers too, this was a safe way to ensure that every one was counted.

Answer (score 1):

Get line count.

`for /f "tokens=3*" %%i in ('find /c /v /n /i"" corner.txt') do set /a v=%%i-1`

Then get the last values from 7-th word of the last line:

`for /f "tokens=7*" %%a in ('more corner.txt +%v%')  do set "String="%%b""`

Variable `%String%` keeps the values framed by double quotes: `Cup&2!/Cup$2!`

If you use `/` as delimiter you can get last value:

`for /f "delims=/ tokens=2*" %%a in (%String%) do @echo %%a`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings in batch files is never ideal but this seems to work:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo.line 1 > "%temp%\SO_Test.txt"
echo. >> "%temp%\SO_Test.txt"
echo.foo^&bar!baz hello/world Cup^&2!/Cup$2!>> "%temp%\SO_Test.txt"
goto start


:start
set "line="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%temp%\SO_Test.txt") do @set line=%%a

:word
set "b="
rem Delims is slash, tab, space and the order is important
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=/  " %%A in ("%line%") do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "b=%%B"
)
if not "%b%" == "" (
    set "line=%b%"
    goto word
)


echo.Last word is "%line%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q70761955.txt"

SET "amper=&"

FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "lastword=%%b"
:: Replace ampersands with spaces, then slashes with spaces
CALL SET "lastword=%%lastword:%amper%= %%"
SET "lastword=%lastword:/= %"
FOR %%b IN (%lastword%) DO SET "lastword=%%b"
ECHO last "word" is -^>%lastword%^<-

GOTO :EOF
```

Read each line of the file, retaining the last-read line in `lastword`.

Replace each "delimiter" character (`&` and `/` are implied in the question. Others - no information.)

Select the last "word" in the last line.

You would need to change the value assigned to `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

I used a file named `q70761955.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this in a `batch-file` run by `cmd` on `windows`.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "((Get-Content -Path 'corner.txt' -Last 1) -split '[\s*/]')[-1]"') DO (SET "LINE7=%%A")
ECHO %LINE7%
```

If the script were written in PowerShell instead of cmd language, it could be a one-liner.

```
$Line7 = ((Get-Content -Path 'corner.txt' -Last 1) -split '[\s*/]')[-1]
```

Comment: I do not think this was downvoted because it does not work. What other reason would there be?